# Inheritage code in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a problem writing in mySQL. I have made a conpectual model of my databas but have no idea how apply it in mySQL.

I have made an inheritage tree of vehicle as my superentity which devides into new and old vehicle and a subentity. Thereafter it will devide into tractors, motorvehicle and so on. All the subentities have the same atributes, such as brand, motorpower and so on.

I have an idee of how I would like to build it but NO IDEA of how to code it. Can I please get som guidance.

Comment: Is it about translating relations into mysql tables, or is it about translating a conceptual scheme (ER?, UML?) into relations?

Comment: I have the conceptual scheme  I have problem transalating it into the relations into mySQL tables YES :) 

So I have my vechilas that are
Old and new - each of them contain tractors, forest machines and construction machines

all the vehical have the same attributes that are
Brand, production year, fuel, fuel consumption, motor power

Answer (score 0):

Hm - there are several ways of implementing a conceptual scheme in a DB; database courses usually spend 10 slides to this topic, so I cannot handle and discuss them all here. But I make one guess that should fit:

I suppose that a vehicle is either old or new, but not both.

Then I'd make one base table for vehicle. The distinction between `new` and `old` is done through a discriminator attribute `isNew`; As you mentioned multiple inheritance, I assume that a vehicle can be a tractor and a forest machine at the same time; Hence I'd place a separate boolean indicator for each of these types:

```
create table vehicle (
  id int primary key,
  isNew bool not null,
  isTractor bool,
  isForestMachine bool,
  ...
  brand varchar(20),
  productionYear int,
  ...
);
```

If a vehicle cannot be of several types the same time, then a single discriminator attribute for type would be better:

```
create table vehicle (
  id int primary key,
  isNew bool not null,
  type ENUM('tractor', 'forest', 'construction'),
  brand varchar(20),
  productionYear int,
  fuel int,
  fuelcon int,
  motorpower int);
```

Comment: The vehiclas can not be of the same type. This DB im creating is a made up one. So i have a company that sells old and new macines that are tractors, forest machines and construction machines is what I offer, So the DB table I would like to show is " old/new machine , the type of machine, and then the attributes". if it make more sense now. 

We talked in class about inheritance but just how to write it in the conceptual scheme but never in the DB.

Comment: So example 2 should work for you - see edited answer

Comment: create table vehicle (
  id int primary key,
  isNew bool not null,
  type ENUM('tractor', 'forest', 'construction'),
 isold bool not null,
  type ENUM('tractor', 'forest', 'construction'),
  brand varchar(20),
  productionYear int,
  fuel int,
  fuelcon int,
  motorpower int);

Comment: when i write this i get an error says  "Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'type' 0.062 sec"

Comment: you have entered `type ENUM ...` twice. See edited answer, in which I took over all you attributes, removed duplicate `type` and attribute `isOld` (which is obsolete since every vehicle that is not `isNew` automatically is old.

Comment: I belive that I have solve it now. thank you for your kind suppot

Comment: You are welcome; please be so kind and mark the answer as accepted such that it is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing object-oriented model design, you often create superclasses and subclasses.

For example, you might create a superclass called `vehicle`. Then, you might create classes that inherit from `vehicle` called, I guess, `roadVehicle` and `offroad`. Then a class inheriting from `roadVehicle` might be `car`. &c. &c.

This sort of design is not very helpful when you are laying out tables for a relational database management system like MySQL (or Oracle or the rest).  Why not?  Class inheritance is not easy to translate conceptually into database tables.

So, instead you need one table, containing all the descriptive attributes for each kind of vehicle.  Each row of your table describes one vehicle.

So, you might have columns for

```
  id             an autoincrementing id
  is_new         boolean.  true means new, false means used.
  make           "Volvo", "International Harvester", &c.
  model          "50D", "King Cab", etc.
  year           the model year of the machine text like "2001", "2015a"
  date_of_manufacture  a date field
  vehicle_type   a text string. "car", "log truck", "tractor", and so forth
  engine_type    a text string "diesel" "gasoline", "electric", "diesel-electric" &c.
  engine_power   75kW, etc. maybe a number if everything is in kW.
  number_of_wheels   4 for a car. 18 for a tractor-trailer, etc
  tool          text. blank for cars.  "Log grapple," maybe, for a log truck
  description   text.  "Staffan's old Citroen" for example.
  registration_locale   text.  SE, US, DE, etc.
  registration_number    text. ABC-123  etc.
```

You get the idea.  If you want to see information about used cars you give this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE is_new = 0 AND vehicle_type = 'car'
```

The disadvantage of this is that you must include columns for all the common attributes in a single table.  Cars don't have tools, so you're wasting a column for car. Forest machines may not have registration numbers, so you're wasting that column for them.

But it doesn't matter. It's a straightforward, and maintainable, way to build a database.